# How to take for loop output to separate array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, hashmap

I need to take following code output to separate array for use another calculation. In this example output is,

```
z count is= 1                                                                                
y count is= 3                                                                                      
x count is= 2.
```

I need to take 1, 3, 2 to separate array. How I do it? I am new to Java.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ForArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> termFreqMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> wordFreqMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        name.add("x");
        name.add("y x");
        name.add("y z y");

        // count words
        for (int j = 0; j < name.size(); j++) {
            String tempname = name.get(j);
            String[] result = tempname.split(" ");
            for (String s : result) {
                Integer twf = wordFreqMap.get(s);
                if (twf == null)
                    wordFreqMap.put(s, new Integer(1));
                else {
                    wordFreqMap.put(s, new Integer(++twf));
                }
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : wordFreqMap.entrySet()) {
            String tempWord = entry.getKey();
            Integer wf = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(tempWord + " " + "count is= " + wf);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a int array with the **size of the Hashmap** so that both hashmap size and array size will be similar. And while iterating the Hashmap save the result in array.
The catch with this is hashmap doesn't have insertion order so the array will not be in insertion order.So you may not know the count is for what key.For that you can create one keys array and put the keys also there for one to one mapping of keys array and countarray.

```
    int countArray[]  = new int[wordFreqMap.size()];
    int i=0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : wordFreqMap.entrySet()) {
        String tempWord = entry.getKey();
        Integer wf = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(tempWord + " " + "count is= " + wf);
        countArray[i++] = wf;

    }
```

Comment: I tried to take a print output using,                                                                                              System.out.println("Array output" + countArray[i]);                                                                 But it gave an error as "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3".

Comment: It is worked with,                                                                                                                 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(countArray));                                                                Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: you should access array to less than the size, if size is 3 , access upto 2 .

Comment: If I need to take output as System.out.println(countArray[i]);  for further calculation. How can I take it? Because it gave "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3" error ? (I am new to java)

Comment: for(i=0;i<countArray.length;i++)
         System.out.println(countArray[i]);